# Regular expression that simply returns the input string

Tags: regex

I realize that this is sort of a silly question, but I need a regular expression that will simply return whatever is passed to it.

So, for instance, if the input string is ABC123, I want the regular expression to return ABC123.

The reason for this is that I need a "catch all" situation.  I am storing a set of regular expressions in a database (one or more for each customer); however some customers don't have a need for any input string parsing...I just want to use what they are passing in as the matched text.

Comment: Please show your use case so we can help come up with a better "catch all" situation, but: [`.*`](http://regex101.com/r/mI1uW1). (explanation: `.` matches any character, `*` matches 0+ times)

Comment: Well, there is plenty of regular expression that can catch the whole string. In the case ABC123 it could be /[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}/, or /[A-Z0-9]+/, or /.+/... I'm not sure to understand correctly your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[\s\S]*
```

This will catch ALL characters.

Comment: Or `.*` with the dot-matches-all setting.

Comment: Just as a heads up to OP, this should technically work with any character class (`[\d\D]*` or `[\w\W]*`).  I still would suggest using the correct modifiers and `.*` though.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for white space or not any whitespace groups repeated.
For instance:

`[\s\S]*`

or

`[\s.]*`

See the bottom of
http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Comment: Incidentally, `.` would also match `\s`.

Comment: `.` does not match newlines or carriage returns

Comment: Depending on the language, you should use a modifier for that. In [Ruby](http://www.rubular.com/r/JVZpEQe72s), `.` matches new lines and with [PHP](http://regex101.com/r/iF0xW9) using the `s` modifier will make `.` match new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one is saying it, I will go ahead.  Keep it simple and use `.*`.  Depending on your regular expression flavor, `.` may **not** match new-lines.  However, there should be a [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for that.  For instance, in PHP the `s` modifier makes dots match new lines.  In Ruby, this behavior is on by default.

```
<?hp
preg_match('/.*/s', "ABC\n123", $matches);

var_dump($matches);
// array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "ABC\n123" }
```

You can also see other peoples' examples of using a character class like `[\s\S]*`.  But I'm assuming a character class will take (minimally) longer to parse than a `.`.

> `(?s)` for "single line mode" makes the dot match all characters, including line breaks. Not supported by Ruby or JavaScript. In Tcl, `(?s)` also makes the caret and dollar match at the start and end of the string only.